# SignedXml.CheckSignature Performance Issue

Tags: .net, xml, digital-signature, xml-signature

I have an issue with checking the signature of an XML file using .NET 3.5. It all works fine, but randomly the performance is poor. Sometimes it's instant and yet at other times it can take maybe 10 or 15 seconds to return.

I've checked the machine and nothing is going on to affect it's overall performance, and it's the same on different machines as well, so I don't think it's related to one machine.

I've narrowed it down precisely to the .CheckSignature() method, so once it hits that it's anybody's guess when it'll come back.

Anyone have any thoughts or advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back at old unanswered questions I thought I'd post an update to this that might prove useful to somebody.

Whilst I didn't find an answer to the performance issue, what I did was kick off the validation of the signature in a separate thread which allowed me to display a dialog box with a progress bar on it showing the user that something was happening, rather than the app seemingly hanging.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you have external references. I stumbled across a posting somewhere that checksignature can make webrequests for any external references

Comment: Nope, no external references.